# Node.js and Express.js Error : Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, express

I am new to node land and I have a case like below where I first want to set a cookie and then redirect to other url. But I get the error - `Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent`.

```
user_details = [req.body.user_name, req.body.user_email, req.body.user_contact, req.body.route_id];
var user_details_str = JSON.stringify(user_details);
res.cookie('user_details', user_details_str, {maxAge : 7 * 24 * 3600000, httpOnly:false});
res.redirect('/route1');
```

I went through this [Node.js Error: Can't set headers after they are sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent) and understood that `res.redirect()` is trying to rewrite the header but don't know how to solve this issue.

EDIT : Complete code.

```
router.post('/register', encryptor.encryptUserPassword, function(req, res, next) {
  req.body.confirmed = false;

  Models.users.create(req.body).then(function(user) {


    user_details = [req.body.user_name, req.body.user_email, req.body.user_contact, req.body.route_id];
    var user_details_str = JSON.stringify(user_details);
    res.cookie('user_details', user_details_str, {maxAge : 7 * 24 * 3600000, httpOnly:false});

    user.user_pass = '';
    sess = res.session;
//    sess.email = user.user_email;
    Models.user_ride.create({user_id:user.user_id,route_id:req.body.route_id}).then(function(userroute){
        res.send(user);
    });

    res.redirect('/route1');
  }).error(function(err) {
    res.send(err);
  }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function(err) {
    res.send(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you're posting, so I'm guessing you're not showing all the relevant code.

Comment: Try `return res.redirect('/route1');`

Comment: @robertklep Posted the complete code in edit.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is this part:

```
Models.user_ride.create({user_id:user.user_id,route_id:req.body.route_id}).then(function(userroute){
    res.send(user);
});

res.redirect('/route1');
```

You're both sending a response using `res.send()` *and* performing a redirect using `res.redirect()`. You need to choose one or the other.